# Excel not summing values between certain dates

Tags: excel

Looking to create a function that takes purchases based on dates and sums them if they fall within a certain time period - from different worksheets.

I have the following so far:

```
=INDEX(Balanced!H1:H100,SUMIF(Balanced!E1:E100,AND(date>1/3/2017,date<31/3/2017),Balanced!H1:H100),)
```

H represents the purchases that need to be summed
E represents the dates of each purchase

But it is returning zero, even though the real total for that month is not.

Comment: Use `SUMIFS`, and follow the function wizard so you enter `sum_range`, `criteria_range`, and `criteria` appropriately.

Comment: I am highly doubtfull you can define your dates the way you have.

Comment: What is the purpose of the INDEX?  right now you are trying to ask it to return the row in column H where the row number is equal to your sum.  So you sum better be an integer between 1 and 100.

Comment: are your dates stored as TEXT or are they stored in excel date format?  `ISTEXT(A1)` where A1 is a cell containing a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To SUM between the dates, try

```
=SUMIFS(Balanced!$H$1:$H$100,Balanced!$E$1:$E$100,">"&DATE(2017,3,1),Balanced!$E$1:$E$100,"<" & DATE(2017,3,31))
```

Note that you will NOT include the values of 1-3 and 31-3 in your sum due to the way you wrote your original formula.

You can still wrap it in the INDEX function, although that is a pretty unusual use.  If the SUM is > 100 or < 1, it will return an error, otherwise it will return a value from column H that corresponds to the row number computed by your `SUMIFS`.